# Spring Boot 1.4.3 / servlet api 3.1 Request cannot be cast to custom CustomServletRequestWrapper which extends standard HttpServletRequestWrapper

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jetty, servlet-filters, undertow

I have implemented a custom servlet request wrapper which extends standard `HttpServletRequestWrapper` for XSS security vulnerabilities.

However when I hit my application URL configured via Spring Boot 1.4.3 both (Jetty or Undertow) display error message as :

```
Request cannot be cast to com.example.rest.security.api.DemoServletRequestWrapper.
```

Not sure what is causing this issue as my custom servlet request wrapper is extending standard `HttpServletRequestWrapper`.

I have tried both with latest Jetty and Undertow spring boot starters. However I still get similar exception stack trace message.

Any pointers as How to resolve this issue and what is the root cause of the issue?

My application is a Spring Boot RESTFul web service flat jar.

Below are my Spring Boot / Jetty dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.3.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:1.4.3.RELEASE")
```

OR Undertow

```
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:1.4.3.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:1.4.3.RELEASE")
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.5'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Below is Jetty stack trace

```
2017-01-12 11:17:28.054  INFO 6340 --- [main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Started DemoApplication in 5.198 seconds (JVM running for 5.771)
2017-01-12 11:19:15.505  WARN 6340 --- [qtp1991294891-13] o.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler   : /demo/v1.0/api/gateway

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request cannot be cast to com.example.api.rest.security.api.DemoServletRequestWrapper
    at com.example.api.filters.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:30) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582) [jetty-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) [jetty-security-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) [jetty-server-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180) [jetty-server-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512) [jetty-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112) [jetty-server-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) [jetty-server-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534) [jetty-server-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320) [jetty-server-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) [jetty-server-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) [jetty-io-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) [jetty-io-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93) [jetty-io-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303) [jetty-util-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148) [jetty-util-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136) [jetty-util-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671) [jetty-util-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589) [jetty-util-9.3.14.v20161028.jar!/:9.3.14.v20161028]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
```

Below is undertow stack trace

```
2017-01-11 16:26:15.486  INFO 12372 --- [main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Started DemoApplication in 3.805 seconds (JVM running for 4.325)
2017-01-11 16:26:24.680 ERROR 12372 --- [XNIO-3 task-1] io.undertow.request                      : UT005023: Exception handling request to /demo/v1.0/api/gateway

java.lang.ClassCastException: io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl cannot be cast to com.example.api.rest.security.api.DemoServletRequestWrapper
    at com.example.api.filters.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:30) ~[classes!/:na]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) ~[undertow-core-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) ~[undertow-core-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175) ~[undertow-servlet-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:207) ~[undertow-core-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:802) [undertow-core-1.3.25.Final.jar!/:1.3.25.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
```

Below is the source code.

```
/* Main Spring Boot application */

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(AppConfig.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

App configuration with XSS Filter registration bean

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean xssFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        XSSFilter xssFilter = new XSSFilter();
        registration.setFilter(xssFilter);
        registration.setName("XSSFilter");
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/v1.0/*");
        return registration;
    }
}
```

Spring Boot Jersey Config for RESTful services implementation

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        registerEndpoints();
    }

    private void registerEndpoints() {
        register(DemoEndPoint.class);
    }
}
```

Demo End Point REST service

```
@Component
@Path("/api")
public class DemoEndPoint {
    @GET
    @Path("/gateway")
    public String test() {
        return "API Gateway!";
    }
}
```

XSS Filter implementation

```
public class XSSFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XSSFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response,
                         final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        LOGGER.debug("doFilter - Entry");
        LOGGER.debug("doFilter - Checking http request body for XSS vulnerabilities");
        final DemoServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = (DemoServletRequestWrapper)request;
        LOGGER.debug("doFilter - Request body = {}", requestWrapper.getBody());
        final String body = EncodeHtmlContent(requestWrapper.getBody());
        LOGGER.debug("doFilter - Request body encoded to {}", body);
        requestWrapper.setBody(body);
        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
 }
}

/* DemoServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper */

I have implemented all the methods of standard `HttpServletRequestWrapper` in this class. For brevity I am displaying only one method in my stack query.

public class DemoServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper implements
        HttpServletRequest {

    private String body;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoServletRequestWrapper.class);

    public MifidServletRequestWrapper(final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        super(request);
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            final InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                final char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                    stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("");
            }
        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error whilst creating the DemoServletRequestWrapper", ex);
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (final IOException ex) {
                    LOGGER.error("Error whilst creating the DemoServletRequestWrapper", ex);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        body = stringBuilder.toString();

    }
```

Implemented all the methods and able to compile my build successfully

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, which XSS are you trying to prevent. Do you have a link to an article?

Comment: And why should that request be able to be cast to your implementation. It is a `RequestWrapper` so you should WRAP the incoming request not cast it to the implementation you want.

Comment: @Deinum - To have more control on the request object and validate security flags / headers to incoming request, I would prefer to create my own custom request wrapper. I have similar custom request wrapper running on JBoss 6.x instance with no issues. I would like to know the root cause as why this custom wrapper implementation does not work with Spring Boot embedded container. I would appreciate for any pointers. Thanks.